# Safely install mysql on windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql

What are some important points to consider when installing mysql 5.1 on windows webserver 2008?

I never installed mysql on any production windows server, so apart from not using the default user root with empty password - what else should be considered in order to safely install the mysql database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of standard stuff applies.

Make sure that there are no open ports from the Internet (via hardware or software firewall, preferable hardware).
Make sure that MySQL is running under an account which has the least permissions possible.
Fast storage for the database and transaction logs

I'm sure there's lots of others that people can suggest.

Comment: i found this installation guide: http://www.analysisandsolutions.com/code/mysql-tutorial.htm -- it sounds very complicated. Is installing mysql really as tough as it sounds?

Comment: Installing MySQL is actually pretty simple.  It has an install wizard just like other applications which walks you though the process.